# Why didn't the mask work in front of Dr Neuman?

Tags: movie, the-mask

In *The Mask*, Ipkiss at one point goes to Dr. Neuman's office to get his opinion on what the mask is and how and why it works

Dr. Neuman thinks that Ipkiss is crazy, and when Ipkiss puts on the mask to show him that he's not, the mask just doesn't work

Why didn't the mask work at that point? Ipkiss says that maybe the mask only works at night (since it had Loki's power in it, and Loki was a god of night) but is that the real reason? Is there a better, more official reason?

Comment: [It works](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ItWasHereISwear), [I swear](https://media.giphy.com/media/RXubI8N92hMLC/giphy.gif)

Comment: [Rule of funny](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny)

Comment: Are we talking about the movie or the comic series?  they're separate continuities.

Comment: **Beware, above commenters linked to TV Tropes**.  Also, @MagikarpMaster: The referenced scene occurred in the movie, so that's the continuity I'm assuming.  That said, I haven't read the comics or seen the cartoon, so I can't be certain the scene wasn't repeated in those continuities.

Comment: The first movie is unique in that it does not refer to the mythological connection to Loki.  The comic series, the ghastly sequel, and I think the cartoon refer to The Mask as "the mask of Loki", but the first movie does not.

Comment: Maybe it didn't work because he was too nervous? Is Norse magic subject to performance anxiety?

Comment: In the first film Dr Neuman makes a reference to Loki. Stanley assumes his mask has Loki's power, possibly misunderstanding what Dr Neuman said.

Comment: Loki was the trickster. Of course he's want to prank Ipkiss.

Comment: @MagikarpMaster Dr. Neuman definitely told Stanley the Mask was (probably) representing Loki, so the reference is there, though not too detailed

Comment: Fair enough, I must have forgotten the mentioning of Loki.  However, in my defense, the Loki angle was not a central theme of the story, nor was it integral to the plot of the first Mask movie.  It could have been "The Mask of Freud" and the plot of the story would not have been affected.  From what I can tell, the same cannot be said for the son of the mask.

Answer (score 41):

The only time Stanley tries the mask on during daylight is at Dr Neuman's. That and the fact that he always woke up without the mask (which he most certainly did not actively remove) suggest his explanation is indeed correct.

Answer (score 20):

Assuming that you are talking about the movie, there is an admittedly speculative theory.

It is possible that the environment of Dr Neuman's office made the effects of The Mask redundant.

In the first Mask movie, there is a theme of masks (duh) and how we all wear masks metaphorically speaking.  We suppress our id (as in id, ego and super ego) by hiding our true selves from the world behind a mask.

Stanley Ipkiss, an incredibly repressed individual, finds The Mask and by wearing it he is able to express his deepest desires.  The Mask essentially reveals his id.

Now, in a therapist's office, one can find oneself admitting things that one cannot even admit to oneself.  One of the key skills a therapist has to learn is how to get their clients to open up and speak honestly to them.  To drop their mask (metaphorically speaking).

It is possible that in that office, where Stanley feels free to express himself fully, that The Mask has no effect because there is nothing more to reveal.

Please remember that this answer is speculative, but based on the content of the first movie.  This answer would not apply to the comic series, and I doubt it would apply to the sequel movie (I have not subjected myself to that yet).

Additional Information:  I recently remembered that this theory may be canon with the cartoon series (for what that is worth).  There is an episode in which Stanley decides to throw away his inhibitions and act as he pleases, and then discovers that The Mask refuses to work when he puts it on.

Comment: Interesting theory. Do the comics show the Mask working in daylight?

Comment: The cartoon certainly does.  But like I said, this theory really only works in the context of the first movie (it took a lot of liberties with the source material since the source material was so violent)

Answer (score 1):

According to TV Tropes.com, the mask has its own personality/intelligence and can work in the daytime but wanted Stanley to look like a buffoon in front of the doctor, so didn't change at that moment (this page was from the cartoon adaptation, but it supposedly takes up where the movie left off- though why Stanley got the mask back when he threw it away at the film's end is left unexplained).

Comment: Interesting. Can you provide a reference for this? Does this mean there are occurrences of the Mask working in daylight in the comics?

Comment: @Zommuter- I was referring to the cartoon tv series, not the comics. I suck at providing links and all that, so I would suggest looking up the Mask at tvtropes.com. That said I haven't read the comics so for all I know it could work during daylight in them too.